# How can I roll back to previous MinecraftPE version?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We are still using an iPad1 iOS 5.1.1 to play minecraftPE.  We ran an update to minecraft (shouldn't have) and now it won't work at all - crashes, freezes, etc.  I have transferred the worlds to my desktop computer so I could uninstall Minecraft, but can someone please tell me how to get the previous version back on the iPads? (Currently it says v0.11.1, so not exactly sure what the prior one was.) Thanks!!!!

Comment: When you download from the app store, it will tell you if there is a latest compatible version available for your os version. YOu confirm. If that is the latest version of the game, then it should work. If you have already downloaded it before then just uninstall and reinstall and it should offer you the most compatible version. :https://sites.google.com/site/appleclubfhs/support/advice-and-articles/app-store-downloading-older-versions-of-apps-ios  as well as here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201377

Answer (score 1):

Great question!
Ive been wondering this as well.
It turns out, that after some research.....
So far, there is not an update to allow you to change mcpe versions, so the best you can do is to report it on the mcpe website and request an update for this to be made. You can also wait, of course, but it will be less effective.